# How to use a joined variable from a list as a string parameter

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list which is constantly updated

for example:

```
list_a = [ 'BTC', 'BUSD', 'ETH', 'BTC']
```

my string variable is:

```py
string = list_a[0]+list_a[1] # when printed this gives BTCBUSD
needed_string=("'{}'".format(string)) #when printed this gives 'BTCBUSD', which seems correct to me
#also tried to add : str(needed_string), gives same string when printed as above
```

If I pass `needed_string` as a parameter in a function it does not work.

If I type `needed_string = 'BTCBUSD'`  it does work

How can I fix this?

Edit:

The list contains crypto coins

The string is combined pair, example 'BTCBUSD'

The string is needed as parameter for a ticker

```py
ticker = client.get_ticker(symbol=needed_string)
```

This is my error:

```
Illegal characters found in parameter 'symbol'; legal range is '^[A-Z0-9-_.]{1,20}$'
```

Comment: please clarify the question. what are you trying to do with the parameter. You say it doesn't work but how exactly does it not work? What were you expecting?  Do you want `needed_string = "'ab'"` or just `needed_string = 'ab'` ?   
In one of these, the quotes are also included in the string

Comment: Can you show your function? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to 'add' the strings together:

```py
list_a = [ 'BTC', 'BUSD', 'ETH', 'BTC'] 
ticker = client.get_ticker(symbol=list_a[0]+list_a[1])
```

Comment: Yes, this does work. but the added strings are not always is this order, there are quite a lot if:/else: statements where 'needed_string' is combined in the right way. So one solution can be to ad the ticker to every if:/else: statement. But than i also have to do this for numeral buy / sell orders, so i was hoping for another way...

Comment: That sounds like a new question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Your code produces :

```
"'ab'" # note single+double quotes
```

Try this :

```
needed_string=('{}'.format(string))
```

It should give :

```
'ab'
```

Comment: `string = ('{}'.format(string))` doesn't make any change to `string`. Not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Paul Lemarchand  In the end that's exactly what I am trying to do xD  ... whole .format() part can also be left out (as quamrana pointed out and I just noticed)